# 503 Service Unavailable Error EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER",

Tags: iis

this error occur this couple days when I try to reach my app 
I verified the pool the IIs config It's OK 
when we activate the IIS tace I got this warning 
[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfXo3.png)

Comment: Do you know if anything changed (patches, security, new code/deployment) in the past few days (between when it was last working vs now)?

Comment: is there a way to check traces ?

Comment: Sometimes Windows (NT) event viewer has really good/useful information with better details about a problem.  Look at both "Application" and "System" events.

Comment: Sorry. I should've looked at your picture.  That message "System too busy" is interesting.  I would use 1) TaskMan to see just how busy the server really is.  2) Maybe also PerfMon to see which resources are getting the most. 3) IIS logs to see durations. Maybe it is a denial of service attack, or maybe a very slow-running process or run-away process (infinite loop, etc).

Comment: As `AspNetCore_isapi.dll` is already loaded, it is the ASP.NET page `/ocm/default.aspx` or `global.asax` returns the 503 error response. You need to review the relevant source code.

Comment: it's dynamics crm Application can't have  the hand on ASP pages